# Refer to one of many coroutines in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine, ienumerator

Is there a way to have a variable point to one of a number of coroutines in C# in Unity3D?

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    ? something ?  crt;

    private IEnumerator CoroutineA()
    {
    }

    private IEnumerator CoroutineB()
    {
    }

    void Start()
    {
        crt = CoroutineA;
        StartCoroutine(crt);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Recall that Unity has a particular situation with `Func` and `Action`" What should I be recalling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type that you are looking for is a [delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172.aspx). Delegates are similar to function pointers, and are not specific to Unity3D.

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    private delegate IEnumerator CoroutineDelegate();

    private IEnumerator CoroutineA()
    {
    }

    private IEnumerator CoroutineB()
    {
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        CoroutineDelegate crt = CoroutineA;
        StartCoroutine(crt());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, use the fact that `StartCoroutine` function just needs an `IEnumerator` object to start the corresponding coroutine.

This means that you can create variables of type `IEnumerator` and assign your coroutines' return values to them (Recall that a coroutine is indeed a generator, i.e. returns `IEnumerator`).

Then, just call `StartCoroutine` on the variable.
In your example, the field `crt` should have type `IEnumerator`. And in your `Start` method, you should assign to it like this:

```
crt = CoroutineA();
```

Then if you wanted to start its assigned coroutine, do it like this:

```
StartCoroutine (crt);
```